# Positioning Content To Center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position the content of the span id "diet" and h1 tag to the center of the web page. I am currently not sure where exactly I am going wrong in the repositioning.

I tried removing the float property and changing the positioning to absolute and the output was not correct.

Appreciate some feedback on my work.

JSFiddle http://buff.ly/1aaJQKq

Comment: Please post the relevant code here...

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `position:relative;`, `float:left;` from `#welcome` and simply use `margin:auto;`

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/9E4KL/

```
#welcome {
    width: 500px;
    text-shadow: 0 3px 0px #FFF;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add text-align:center; to content in your style sheet

```
  #content {
font-family: monospace;
color: #46C;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 40px 0;
float: left;
width: 100%;
   text-align:center;
 }
```

here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/3caj2/1/

Comment: Be careful if you use content somewhere else but i am assuming that you wont be since it is an ID

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a width to both the logo div and h1 tag (`width: 100%`) and (as Travis also mentioned) center the contents with `text-align: center`.

The CSS rules for the diet tag would look then as follows:

```
#logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 71px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "MARI&DAVID BOLD";
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 7px 10px 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```